# GLTF anim and morph playback issue when using three.js with more than one mixer

Tags: three.js, blender, fbx, gltf

I have a single gltf file, exported from Blender with 6 anims and 20 morph targets. When that's the only skinned gltf object in the scene, everything plays nicely - I can switch between bone anims (run, walk, idle, etc), and get all morph anims (for facial expressions) cycling on a timer, or triggered by events. Yay.

The problem is when I introduce a second skinned object, such as an NPC. At that point lots of weirdness starts to happen.

For example, when morph targets cycle expressions on/off the player object, the NPC model standing nearby scales down and disappears on the off cycle, then scales back up during the on cycle. Another example, at init time the NPC object might randomly turn into an instance of another loaded object (a tree or a building), or occasionally a mini version of some random object, at 10% normal scale, and then start rapidly bouncing around in unpredictable and inconsistent ways. I have no idea what's going on.

I thought it might have something to do with loading multiple mixers, but then that's what the docs state should be done - "When multiple objects in the scene are animated independently, one AnimationMixer may be used for each object." Unless I'm reading that wrong?

I'm using:

```
npcMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(npc);
```

virtually the same as what I do for the player:

```
playerMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(player);
```

Is this a bad/mistaken approach?

Perhaps worth noting: I had FBX versions of the player and NPC working just fine together when exported and accessed as individual files. Then I spent a lot of time converting to GLTF since it's faster and lets me wrap all the actions up in a single file, which the FBX exporter does not seem to support (If I'm wrong about FBX being able to export multiple actions in a single file for playback in the three.js context please let me know!).

Three.js r98

Blender 2.79

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you're passing different objects into each mixer, it sounds like you're doing this right... I'd suggest filing a bug on three.js. If you're able to create a demo that might also help.

Comment: Sorry took a bit to go through and reduce to the core elements to demo the issue: [clicky here](http://nideffer.net/book/html/game/world-so-demo.html). Be a little patient, the morphs on the player (the dude with the cape, note that movement has been disabled) cycle on ~10sec intervals. Within that time you should start to see the magical fragmented disappearing/reappearing act played by the NPC (the guy with the untucked shirt).

Comment: Issue [answered here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/15672). Thanks Don McCurdy.